# How to use the ApexChart component in the component cell in Datatable.net

Tags: datatables, vue-component, vuejs3, apexcharts

I am trying to output a graph in a table cell

component Table.vue

```
<template>
       
          <DataTable
            id="playlists"
            class="display table table-hover"
            :data="props.data"
            :columns="columns"
            :options="options"
            ref="table"
          >
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><i class="fas fa-star"></i></th>
              <th><i class="fas fa-vote-yea"></i></th>
              <th>Наименование</th>
              <th>Треков</th>
              <th>Обновлён</th>
              <th>График</th>
              <th>Прослушиваний</th>
              <th>Автор</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <template v-slot:cell(chart)="props">
              <Chart :series="props"></Chart>
            </template>
          </DataTable>
</template>

<script async setup lang="ts">
import DataTable from "datatables.net-vue3";
import DataTablesLib from "datatables.net-bs5";
import "datatables.net-select";
import "datatables.net-responsive-bs5";
import moment from "moment-timezone";
import { onMounted, reactive, ref } from "vue";
import { useDeletePlaylists } from "../use/deletePlaylist";
import { useUpdatePlaylists } from "../use/updatePlaylist";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import Chart from "./Chart.vue";

DataTable.use(DataTablesLib);

let props = defineProps({
  data: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  },
  isFavourites: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  isWork: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  chartOptions: {
  }
});
let dt: any;
const table = ref();
const store = useStore();

// This variable shows static, but data from props.data will be generated into it
let series = ref([{
  name: "",
  data: [{
    x: "2018-09-10 13:50",
    y: 112
  }, {
    x: "2018-09-11",
    y: 321
  }, {
    x: "2018-09-12",
    y: 443
  }]
}]);

const options = {
  responsive: true,
  autoWidth: false,
  language: {
    search: "Поиск",
    info: "с _START_ по _END_ из _TOTAL_",
    select: "выбрано",
    paginate: {
      previous: "prev",
      next: "next"
    },
    zeroRecords: "В Базе данных нет записей"
  },
  select: {
    info: false,
    className: "table-primary",
    blurable: true
  },
  paginate: {
    right: true
  }
};
const columns = [
  {
    data: null,
    render: (row: any) => {
      return `<div><i class="${row.favourites ? "fas" : "far"} fa-star"></i><span style="display: none; z-index: 3">${row.favourites}</span></div>`;
    },
    sort: true
  },
  {
    data: null, render: (row: any) => {
      return `<div><i class="${row.isWork ? "far fa-check-square" : "far fa-square"}"></i><span style="display: none; z-index: 3">${row.isWork}</span></div>`;
    }
  },
  { data: "title" },
  { data: "totalCount" },
  {
    data: null, render: (row: any) => {
      return moment.unix(row.lastUpdated).tz("Europe/Moscow").format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");
    }
  },
  {
    field: 'chart',
    data: series
  },
  {
    data: null, render: (row: any) => {
      return row.listens[0].listens;
    }
  },
  {
    data: null, render: (row: any) => {
      return `<a href="https://vk.com/im?media=&sel=${row.ownerId}" target="_blank">${row.authorName}</a>`;
    }
  }
];

onMounted(async function() {
  dt = table.value.dt;
});
</script>
```

component Chart.vue

```
<template>
<!--  id="chart" style="width: 300px; height: 250px"-->
  <div id="chart">
    <vue-apex-charts type="area" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"></vue-apex-charts>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, onMounted, reactive, ref } from "vue";
import VueApexCharts from "vue3-apexcharts";
import { ApexOptions } from "apexcharts";

const props = defineProps({
  series: {
    type: Array<{}>,
    required: true
  }
})

let chartOptions: ApexOptions = reactive({
  chart: {
    type: "area",
    toolbar: {
      show: false
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: false
    },
    sparkline: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  xaxis: {
    labels: { show: false },
    axisBorder: {
      show: false
    }
  },
  yaxis: {
    show: false
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  stroke: {
    show: false,
    curve: "smooth",
    lineCap: "butt",
    width: 1
  },
  tooltip: {
    show: false,
    x: {
      format: "dd MMM"
    },
    marker: {
      show: false
    }
  }
})

let series = computed(()=> {
  console.log(props.series);
  return props.series;
})

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(props.series);
});


</script>
```

I got this error/issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH0pu.png)

in the Table component.msu has a series variable, it is still static for example, later data from props.data will be generated into it

I tried using the render function

```
  {
    data: null, render: () => {
      `<Chart :series="${series}"></Chart>`
    }
  },
```

It didn't work